# gem install bouncy-castle-java for full support

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jruby, rsa, jrubyonrails

I am getting this warning message on the deployment server, when I start the server or running the console.

```
OpenSSL ASN1/PKey/X509/Netscape/PKCS7 implementation unavailable
gem install bouncy-castle-java for full support.
```

Also, When I try to generate the Key with following command.

```
OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(PUBLIC_KEY)
```

I get following exception

```
OpenSSL::PKey::RSAError: Neither PUB key nor PRIV key:
    from org/jruby/ext/openssl/PKeyRSA.java:278:in `initialize'
```

I am  bit confused with the message. I have the bouncy-castle-java installed on the machine. But I am still confused with message.

I am not sure abt the issue. Can anyone explain the issue, Or give me some directions.

Comment: Hey, I installed jruby openssl 0.8.8 in the server that fixed the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this issue on my end by installing jruby openssl 0.8.8 on the server.

As far as I remember there was an conflict with jruby and openssl gem that was used in the gem list(So I had to update the Gem)